# Imprimir texto en al presionar boton arduino

Tags: c, botón, arduino

Buenas   estoy haciendo una practica en **arduino** de que al presionar un boton se muestra secuencia de leds , en cuanto a la programacion de la secuencia todo esta bien el problema es que quiero que se muestre un texto en el monitor en serie que indique la suecuencia que se esta reproduciendo

Este el codigo de la secuencia todo esto funciona bien

```
int n;
    int btnu=2;
    int btnd=3;
    int btnt=4;
    int btnc=1;
    void setup() { 
    
    for (n=5;n<9;n++) 
    
    { 
    
      pinMode (n, OUTPUT); 
      pinMode (btnu,INPUT);
      pinMode (btnd,INPUT);
      pinMode (btnt,INPUT);
    
} 

} 
 //metodos para cada secuencia
void secuencia(){ //secuencia amarillo,rojo,verde,blanco

  for (n=8;n>4;n--) 

  { 

    digitalWrite (n, HIGH); 

    delay (300); 

    digitalWrite (n, LOW); 

    delay (500); 

  } 

} 

void secuencia2 (){ //blanco,verde,rojo,amarillo
 for (n=5;n<9;n++) 

  { 

    digitalWrite (n, HIGH); 

    delay (300); 

    digitalWrite (n, LOW); 

    delay (500); 

  } }
void secuencia3 () {  //secuencia verde,rojo,blanco,amarillo
  digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  delay(600);
   digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(6,LOW);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  delay(600);
   digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(6,LOW);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  
  delay(600);
   digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
  digitalWrite(6,LOW);
 digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  
  
  delay(600);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
}
void secuencia4(){ // amarillo,verde -> blanco,rojo
   digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
   digitalWrite(6,LOW);
  digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  delay(1000);
   digitalWrite(5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);
   
  
}
```

En el loop coloque un serial println para que muestra texto de la secuencia que se esta reproduciendo

```
void loop() {
  btnu=digitalRead(2);
  btnd=digitalRead(3);
  btnt=digitalRead(4);
  btnc=digitalRead(1);

  if (btnu==HIGH){
 secuencia(); 
    Serial.println("Secuencia:Amarillo,rojo,verde,blanco");

}
  else if(btnd==HIGH){
    secuencia2();
   Serial.println("Secuencia:Blanco,verde,rojo,amarillo");}
  else if (btnt==HIGH){
  secuencia3();
   Serial.println("Secuencia:Verde,Rojo,Blanco,Amarillo");}
  else if(btnc==HIGH){
  secuencia4();
     Serial.println("Secuencia:Verde,Amarillo->Blanco,Rojo");
  }
 }
```

El problema es que no se imprime el texto en el monitor en serie al momento  de presionar los botones. Alguna idea de como solucionar esto? Probe metiendo los print en los metodos pero eso tampoco funciona.

*Esta practica la estoy haciendo en un simulador no en una placa de arduino fisica por si eso tiene algo que ver , gracias*

Comment: Estas haciendo la secuencia primero, y cuando esta termina imprimes el texto. ¿Así funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón es que no has abierto la puerta serial; te falta agregar

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

en el `setup()`, asi:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
    
  for (n = 5; n < 9; n++) {
    pinMode (n, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (btnu, INPUT);
    pinMode (btnd, INPUT);
    pinMode (btnt, INPUT);
  }
}
```

#### Demo

Este script, corriendo en un Arduino real, no imprime nada en el Monitor Serial

```
void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("x");
}
```

Este otro si imprime

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("x");
}
```